# Недостаточная точность типа double

Tags: java, алгоритм

У меня есть метод для деления многочленов с остатком. Он хорошо работает для многочленов, коэффициенты которых делятся точно. Но при попытке разделить, например `2*x^3-18*x^2+....` на `7.00000(много нулей)0000028*x^2 + 5*x + ...` возникает проблема. Первым делом делятся коэффициенты при старших членах: `2*x^3 / 7.000...000028*x^2`. Получаем `0.285714....53*x`. Дальше необходимо умножить полученное значение `0.2857....53*x` на делитель `7.00000...0000028*x^2 + 5*x + ..` и вычесть из делимого многочлена `2*x^3-18*x^2+...`. Так мы получаем остаток уже степени 2. Но из-за проблем с точностью вычисления, после вычитания я получаю не многочлен степени 2, а вот такой `2.220....E-16*x^3 - 6*x^2 + ....`. Понятно, что на самом деле возле `x^3` стоит почти ноль, но из-за того, что по факту это не так, алгоритм зацикливается. Как правильно решить эту проблему, чтобы не изобретать велосипедов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы просто старшую степень всегда вычитайте полностью! Зачем же потом опять множить?

```
(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d) / (ex^2+fx+g) => // первый член - ax/e
```

Остаток: `(bx^2+cx+d - (afx^2/e+agx/e))`, дальше делите его...
При члене `x^3` коэффициент **по определению** нулеdой!

Более-менее понятно? жутко не хочется строить все это в TeX'е...

Comment: Да, я понимаю, о чем вы. Думаю, так я и поступлю, Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вы не указали никакого кода, который помог бы решить проблему, ведь она зависит от того, как именно вы сравниваете числа типа `double`. Я догадываюсь, как вы это делаете, а потому предлагаю после произведённых вычислений делать следующее. Если некое число по абсолютному значению меньше чем заданная заранее точность, например, `const double EPS = 1e-8`, то намеренно делаем это число равным нулю. Типа того:

```
if (abs(a) < EPS)  a = 0.0;
```

Был бы код, я бы конкретно показал, где и как это сделать, но, думаю, вы уже и так поняли.

Answer (score 0):

Переписать алгоритм. Он должен только один раз определять степень многочлена, а потом работать так, что на каждой итерации обрабатывается только суффикс массива. Ну и с нулём надо сравнивать с некоторой точностью, как написали в других ответах.

Comment: Это больше похоже на комментарий, чем на ответ. "Когда ваша репутация достигнет бла-бла-бла  вы сможете оставлять комментарии". ;) Ладно, сам вопрос без кода -- так что пусть остаётся.